# Order of Elliptic Curve over Finite Field contradicts Lagrange?

Tags: group-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Please see the attached image for a question on why the order of an elliptic curve does not consider the point at infinity in order to avoid contradicting Lagrange's Theorem.

[Elliptic Curve over Finite Field specific Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KC7u.png)

[Matlab Plotting of the Elliptic Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgs8t.png)

Answer (score 2):

1. It would be convenient for readers if you presented the question in text, not in a picture.
2. Drawing curves over finite fields in MATLAB is not terribly illuminating.
3. This is not an elliptic curve: it is $y^2=(x+4)^2(x+3)$, a rational curve with a node.

Comment: Apologies for the incorrect formatting and the inclusion of a MATLAB graph (I did it to show that I was not pulling the group order number out of my head, but I understand that I could have included a table instead).  Can you please elaborate on why the curve y^2=x^3 - 4x +4 is not an elliptic curve?  The discriminant is non-zero.  Although this is one example, I have noticed that this occurs with other Elliptic Curves.

Comment: @CallumN: The field is $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ here, so the discriminant is zero.

Comment: @CallumN It is not an elliptic curve, since its discriminant is zero. One can see this immediately since the RHS has a repeated factor.

Comment: @ccorn and Lord Shark: So the discriminant is also calculated modulo 11?  Okay, thank you.  I noticed that if the discriminant is non-zero, then the curve has a prime order.  However, does this mean that every point is a generator? When we include the point at infinity, the elliptic curve no longer has prime order, so going back to my original question, do we include the point at infinity? Would doing so violate Lagrange's Theorem?

Comment: You **don't have** an elliptic curve here!

Comment: I tried y^2 = x^3 + x + 3 and others.  The previous one was an example, a bad one, I'll admit.  I just want to know the role of the point at infinity and whether this violates Lagrange.

Comment: @CallumN Lagrange's theorem **is** a theorem, and the points (including the point at infinity) on an elliptic curve **is** a group. There won't be any violation here!

Comment: Yes, which is why I am confused.  For an elliptic curve group with a prime number of elements, either we include the point at infinity in the group order, in which case the order is no longer prime, so the group is no longer cyclic.  Or, we do not include the point at infinity.  Since we know that the group is cyclic, why do we disregard the point at infinity to ensure that Lagrange's theorem is obeyed?

Comment: @callumN: Why do you think the group has to be cyclic?

Comment: @CallumN The problem is that you are talking about a hypotetical counterexample that doesn't exist, because of the same theorems that you mention.

Comment: @ccorn: Either the group is cyclic or not, but I want to use Lagrange's Theorem to find an elliptic curve which has a prime number of elements, so I can find a generator element.  The simplest way I can think of doing so is to find a suitable Elliptic Curve with a suitable Finite Field that has prime order.  However, I do not know in this case what the order refers to.  Does it include the point at infinity or not?

Comment: @CallumN Yes, you have to include the point at infinity, otherwise it won't be a group.

Comment: For any prime number $p$ and any integer between $1+p-2\sqrt p$ and $1+p+2\sqrt p$ there will be an elliptic curve over $k=\Bbb F_p$ with a group of order $m$. So for $p=11$ there is an elliptic curve group of order $11$ and one of order $13$. For small $p$ like $11$, trial and error is as good a way of finding these as any.

Comment: Is that a corollary of Hasse's Theorem?

Comment: @callumN: For $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ and $y^2=x^3+kx+1$, most values of $k\pmod{11}$ except $k=6$ (discriminant zero) and $k=9$ give a cyclic group, Try $k=5$ or $k=8$ for prime group orders.

Comment: In Pari/GP, for $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$: Try `elltors(ellinit(Mod([a,b],p)))` to get group order, structure, and generators. Or `p+1-ellap(ellinit(Mod([a,b],p)))` for the group order only.

Comment: @CallumN It's more of a converse to Hasse's theorem.